# Create array with NaN type value in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, achartengine

I am trying to build a dynamic array to plot a chart in android. I am using AchartEngine library.

The idea is to provide some irrelavant integer such as NaN in javascript so that the chart library will not draw any point for that particular x-axis point but the connecting line between all points. I hope it is clear what I mean here.

From web service I am getting data and the integer would could be in negative so I do not know what to put which would be similar to NaN.

```
JSONObject jObject = reader.getJSONObject("temp");

for(int i = 0; i< jObject.length();i++ ) {
    if((jObject.getJSONArray(Integer.toString(i)).isNull(0))) {
        temp.add(i, -125);  // something here like NaN
        Log.d(TAG, "JArray#1" + jObject.getJSONArray(Integer.toString(i)));
    } else {
        JSONArray j = jObject.getJSONArray(Integer.toString(i));

        temp.add(i,Integer.parseInt(jObject.getJSONArray(Integer.toString(i))
            .getJSONObject(0).getString("value")));
    }
}
```

In Addition when I am checking values for `ArrrayList`, it shows null on the index where I have put -125

In the end, I want array something like this if x-axiz has 7 values then

```
temp = [23, 45, NaN, NaN, 89, -4, -24]
```

I also tried converting Integer ArrayList to Array as well but did not work.

Thanks, I hope question is clear

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
temp = [23, 45, Double.NaN, Double.NaN, 89, -4, -24]
```

Comment: first temp is int array, and I also tried by parsing Double.NaN but did not work

Answer (score 0):

AChartEngine provides the `MathHelper.NULL_VALUE` for the purpose you have described.

Comment: but what is this Mathhelper, I need to define or already exiting

Comment: It's a class in the AChartEngine package.

Comment: But when I put this there is no curve visible...:(